# send regexp matches to an array of strings

Tags: regex, arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to get the code below to send the results of the regexp search to an array of strings. How can I do that?

When I change name to an array of strings i.e. `Dim name() as String` VBA throws a type-mismatch exception. Any idea what I can do to fix that?

Many thanks.

```
 Do While Not EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, sText
    If sText <> "" Then


       Dim Regex As Object, myMatches As Object

       ' instantiates regexp object
       Set Regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
       With Regex
            .MultiLine = False
            .Global = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = "^Personal\sname\s*[:]\s*"
       End With

       ' get name, seperated from Personal Name
       If Regex.test(sText) Then

            Set myMatches = Regex.Execute(sText)
            Dim temp As String
            temp = Regex.Replace(sText, vbNullString)
            Regex.Pattern = "^[^*]*[*]+"
            Set myMatches = Regex.Execute(temp)
            Dim temp2 As String
            temp2 = myMatches.Item(0)
            name = Trim(Left(temp2, Len(temp2) - 3))

        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not use "name" as a variable name as it conflicts with an excel property. Try sName or sNames instead, where s is for string.

With a array you need to give it a size before you can assign a value to each element.

```
Dim sNames(4) As String  '// Or Dim sNames(1 To 4) As String

sName(1) = "John"
...
sName(4) = "Sam"
```

or if you don't know the total number of elements (names) to begin with then:

```
Dim sNames() As String
Dim iTotalNames As Integer

iTotalNames = '// Some code here to determine how many names you will have

ReDim sNames(iTotalNames) '// You can also use ReDim Preserve if you have existing elements

sName(1) = "John"
...
sName(4) = "Sam"
```

So I suspect you will need something like:

```
  Dim sNames() As String
  Dim iTotalNames As Integer

  '// Your code ....

  iTotalNames = iTotalNames + 1
  ReDim Preserve sNames(iTotalNames)
  sNames(iTotalNames) = Trim(Left(temp2, Len(temp2) - 3))

  '// Rest of your code ...
```

Also in VBA all dimensioning of variables should be at the top of the module.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
'call this "A"
Dim temp2 As String
temp2 = myMatches.Item(0)
```

to

```
'stick this at the top
 redim temp2(0 to 0)

'replace "A" with this
 new_top = ubound(temp2)+1
 redim preserve temp2 (0 to new_top)
 temp2(new_top) = myMatches.Item(0)
```